# Align to center/middle elements: no flex, no defined cell size

Tags: css

I need to align a banner containing 3 elements, to center.
[image]

Conditions:
1) All elements should be middle aligned vertically (on the same line);
2) *Marginal* elements (red) should be like "inline-blocks"`[=][=]`, auto size, **no size defined**!
3) *Central* (green) element should take all remaining place, middle align elements vertically and horizontally.
4) I need to support `IE 9`, so **no flex**...

This is my code *with FLEX*, also I see that the right body margin is overflowed...

**[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NhGsf/61/)**

```css
html, body {
    width:100%;
}
.container {
    display: table-row;
    background: yellow;
    width: 100%;
}
.first, .last, .center {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;    
    background: red;
}
.first>div {display: flex;}
.last>div {display: flex;}
.center {    
    background: green;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="cotnainer">
    <div class="first">
        <div>
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/32x40" alt="">
            <div>image 40</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="center">
        <div>
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/16x16" alt="">
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/16x16" alt="">
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/16x16" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="last">
        <div>
            <div>image 50</div>
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/38x50" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How could I eliminate ***flex*** and respect body right default margins(padding)?

Answer (score 0):

### Style the nested elements

This is dirty…

You can use the universal selector `*` to make all children of the nested `div` inline-block elements. Adding `vertical-align: middle` ensures that `img` elements will align properly with the text. Apply `white-space: nowrap` to the parent to make sure they don't wrap.

```
.container > div > div {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.container > div > div > * {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**A working example:**

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
}
.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: yellow;
}
.container > div {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: red;
}
.container > .center {
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}
.container > div > div {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.container > div > div > * {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">
    <div>
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/32x40" alt="">
      <div>image 40</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <div>
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/16x16" alt="">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/16x16" alt="">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/16x16" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="last">
    <div>
      <div>image 50</div>
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/38x50" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```